# Split Result from SQL Query

Tags: sql

For example this SQL statement returns 1k rows

`SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE someCondition`

my question is: is it possible by using WHERE

1) Split Resultset to the 10 partial resultsets, then

- 1st. would be returns 0% - 10%,
- 2nd. 10% - 20%,
- etc..

2) cuts range between 50 - 150th rows

Comment: What RDBMS? What defines order of result sets? Is there a primary key on the table? And do you actually want 10 different result sets or just some kind of `group` column?

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to achieve this? Is it for pagination of results by any chance - if it is, say so, as there are many good solutions for that...

Comment: `What RDBMS ???`, basically syntax for SQL-92 standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using oracle database this is very simple.

you can use ROWNUM keyword to achive this task in following manner..

```
select * from 
( 
     select tb.*,rownum t_count from table_name tb
) ss
where ss.t_count >= @min_value and ss.t_count <= @max_value
```

where @min_value and @max_value is the range for what you want to get data...
actually it will work on concept of inner query and temprory tables.

that's why it will give good performance over fatching all the data in one shot.

Comment: this kick I needed, this's for mainframe, since syntax is longer than required for built-in option means Oracle/MsSQL/Mysql, finally I used BETWEEN

Answer (score 1):

> my question is: is it possible by using WHERE

My answer is: yes, it is possible.

One of the solutions would be to use the `MOD` function.
The `MOD` function returns the remainder of one number divided by another and the function accepts two arguments:

```sql
MOD(dividend,divisor)
```

- `dividend` is a literal number or a numeric expression to divide.
- `divisor` is a literal number or a numeric expression by which to divide the dividend.

In particular, dividing the data into ten parts, in your example, would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 1
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 2
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 3
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 4
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 5
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 6
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 7
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 8
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 9
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mod(INDEX_ID, 10) = 0
```

`INDEX_ID` is *index* from `table_name`.